# How to cut a sphere in 3 parts of equal volume?

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-geometry

I ran across this problem when working on an architecture design project. I know this probably involves integral math but I'm not very familiar with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a spherical segment?  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment) shows it as the area between two planes, so none of the segments can contain the part of the sphere outboard of all the planes.  You could imagine slicing off two parallel spherical caps, each of $1/3$ the volume of the sphere, leaving a spherical segment of $1/3$ the volume.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that 'spherical segment' was defined as such. I just want to slice three parts as you describe, with 2 caps and 1 segment.

Comment: As presently stated, the question can most easily be answered by drawing three meridians from the north pole to the south pole, at angles $0^\circ, 120^\circ,$ and $240^\circ$, and cutting the sphere like an orange into three wedge-shaped sections. I know this isn't the shape you want to cut, but your question doesn't say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to cut off a [spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) with $1/3$ the volume of a sphere, let the radius of the sphere be $r$ and the height of the cap be $h$.  The volume of the cap is $V=\frac {\pi h^2}3(3r-h)$  To have this $1/3$ of the sphere we need $$\frac 49\pi r^3=\frac {\pi h^2}3(3r-h)\\4r^3=9rh^2-3h^3$$  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%3D9x%5E2-3x%5E3) doesn't find a neat solution, but $\frac hr \approx 0.77393$ so cut a cap with height about $3/4$ of the radius off each side and you will have equal volume in each piece.